# Conditional navbar links 'Chat' and 'Logout' show only after on refresh

Tags: reactjs, jwt, react-bootstrap

I have built a conditional navbar for a react application. After the login, it should show a Chat navlink and a Logout navlink straight away if there is a JWT token. However, it only shows them on refresh. Why is this and how can I resolve it?

I am using a JWT object as authorization.

Navbar.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Navbar, Nav} from 'react-bootstrap';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import Logo from '../../logo/blacklogo.png';
import Logout from '../logoutNavLink/logout';
import getJwt from '../../utils/getJwt';
import '../navbar/style.css'

const jwt = getJwt();

class Navigation extends Component {
    state = {
       isAuthenticated: jwt
    }

    render() {

        return (
          <Navbar bg="light" expand="sm">
             <Navbar.Brand href="/">
               <img
                  src={Logo}
                  className="d-inline-block align-top"
                  alt="Soundbudz logo"
               />
            </Navbar.Brand>
            <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
            <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">

              {this.state.isAuthenticated ? (
                <Nav className="ml-auto">
                 <Link to="/chat">Chat</Link>
                 <Logout to="/">Logout</Logout>
                </Nav> 
              ):(
                <Nav className="ml-auto">
                 <Link to="/registration">Registration</Link>
                 <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
                </Nav>
             )}

            </Navbar.Collapse>
           </Navbar>
     )}
}

export default Navigation;
```

Comment: Because `jwt` is not updating the state in the component. You should call your `jwt` updating function inside the component or send the jwt as a prop for the `<Navigation />` component.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set 'isAuthenticated' to null initially and send the jwt as a prop to the navigation component and then create a function in which you check if the jwt exist and if so change the state of isAuthenticated that way the conditional in your return will work

Comment: Can you illustrate this? I've set isAuthenticated to null and passed jwt as a prop to nav component but still it renders after second refresh.